# Google Chrome with minimal layout without address bar, and without tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser

Is there a way to open tab in Google Chrome/Chromium with minimal layout (without tabs, bars, adress bar) so I can watch youtube videos in  small window with borders only? 
Is there a shortcut to switch between this modes or extension to do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok. I found one solution to this problem.

1. Go to desire website
2. Open

   > Main menu -> More Tools -> Create Shortcut
3. Check "Open as window"
4. Open created shortcut from Desktop (Or created shortcut opens automatically)

Enjoy the website with minimal layout.

Comment: Great answer. The only difference is that in Chrome 69 it's "Create Shortcut..." instead of "Add to Desktop"

Comment: There is also a  Chrome plugin Open as Popup that allow to do similar.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-as-popup/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc.

Comment: The create shortcut method doesn't show as a minimal for me. It just opens a normal tab with address bar and more. The popup addon works great.

Comment: @lluke Thank you! This plugin still works fine in the end of 2021.

Answer (score 23):

If you use linux (but maybe there is a way to start it from command line in other less user friendly OSes), you can start youtube with:

```
google-chrome-stable --new-window --app=https://www.youtube.com
```

Comment: with Win10 it is `chrome --new-window --app=https://www.youtube.com`

Comment: from command line, as opposed to "Menu -> Save and Share -> Create Shortcut" you seem to lose the extensions menu and the app menu. Is there a way to replicate the *exact* behaviour of the menu command from command line? Including registering it to `chrome://apps` (like the menu entry does).

Answer (score 6):

For MacOS it is:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --new-window --app=https://my.jdownloader.org/
```

There is some way to make it launch from Launchpad item even with custom icon, but I'd need to google that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked with me!

Answer (score 5):

For the most recent version as of November 2018:

1. Go to Apps,
2. Right-click the desired app
3. Open as window

Enjoy website with minimal layout.

Comment: "Apps" ? Is this in the Chrome Browser or Chromebook?

Answer (score 1):

chrome, google-chrome-stable, chromium, chromium-browser all have a kiosk mode that allows the browser to be used in a single-window/single-app kiosk mode. Essentially, it locks away access to the rest of the device.

Start with:

```
    chrome --kiosk http://google.com/
```

Not sure if that was what you wanted, but it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

**Terms:**

- window decorations of one application: the bar that allows you to maximize/minimize/close.
- OS: Operating System
- OS Task Bar: The bar that displays all the Applications open and allows you to move from one to another.

In a photo:

[image]

---

#### **Options:**

---

**Case 1: Open url directly.**

- NOT VISIBLE: browser toolbars / sidebars / menus / etc
- VISIBLE: application (browser) window decorations
- VISIBLE: OS Task Bar and other OS Desktop items

```
# command
chrome --app="url_to_open"
# Example
chrome  --app="https://www.google.com/"
```

---

**Case 2: Apply to existing (already open) page**

- NOT VISIBLE: browser toolbars / sidebars / menus / etc
- VISIBLE: application (browser) window decorations
- VISIBLE: OS Task Bar and other OS Desktop items

1. Save the shortcut below (one way is drag & drop)

[Detach](https://Replace_the_whole_url_for_the_script)  << This is called a bookmarklet

2. Edit the shortcut and replace the full url with this

```
javascript:window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0"); window.close()
```

3. Click the bookmark when the page/tab you want to detach is focused

---

**Case 3: Apply to existing (already open) page**

- NOT VISIBLE: browser toolbars / sidebars / menus / etc
- NOT VISIBLE: application (browser) window decorations
- NOT VISIBLE: OS Task Bar and other OS Desktop items

Press **F11** for 'Full screen' mode.

---

**Case 4: Open url directly.**

- NOT VISIBLE: browser toolbars / sidebars / menus / etc
- NOT VISIBLE: application (browser) window decorations
- NOT VISIBLE: OS Task Bar and other OS Desktop items

Look for '**kiosk mode**'. Depending on the OS it differs a bit (I couldn't make it work)

Answer (score 0):

Use the microsoft powertoys app in the microsoft store or in the official github https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys there's a function called crop and lock which allows you to crop a window as well as lots of other useful functions
Edit : i just found out another thing after searching a bit.
You can use this tag which should work on any chromium browser(chrome/edge/etc) --app=http://google.com